# Open a file only once in a for-loop if condition is met

Tags: python, file, for-loop, if-statement

I have the following Python code:

```
for i in range(large_number):
  # compute a_i
  if a_i is condition:
    # Need to make change here for the file open
    f = open('file.log', wb)
    # more computations proceeding. Cannot use break
```

Now that I can achieve opening file only once by

```
needs_fopen = False
for i in range(large_number):
  # compute a_i
  if a_i is condition:
    needs_fopen = True

if needs_fopen is True:
  f = open('file.log', wb)
```

I do not want to do the second approach due to my code complexity. How to achieve the first method but open the file only once if the condition is satisfied?

Comment: What about opening the file before you enter the loop? Yes, it might not be needed but I don't think it's too much overhead.

Comment: I want to open the file only if the condition is met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = None
for i in range(large_number):
  # comput a_i
  if a_i is condition and not f:
    f = open('file.log', wb)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `any()` with a generator comprehension:

```
if any(i is condition for i in range(number)):
  f = open('file.log', wb)
```

Comment: I am sorry. I made an update. My requirement is different.